# deleting nodes from a view

Tags: views, 7

I have created view which displays a list of nodes. I made a custom module with a function which calls db_query() to delete the specified node in the list. I made a Global:Custom Text  field in the view which I made into a link to point to that function. The link works perfectly, the node is deleted from the database table, but now the view still lists a blank line (where that node used to be) which still has the Global:Custom Text field there. How can I get rid of this line completely?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module? This is a great module for updating and deleting nodes from Views.

Comment: It definitly does look like a useful module. But since I have already created everything myself except for this last issue, do you have an idea how I could do this myself?

Comment: use node_delete() or node_delete_multiple() instead of db query , but for my opinion , Views bulk operation would be the best Solution

Comment: I have been looking for a good tutorial on node_delete() and I can't find one. It takes one parameter, $nid. In the function I mentioned above, how can it know what the $nid is? Is it automatically passed when I click the link in the view?

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks, that was the exact thing I needed!